# stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 128, 128] at entry 0 and [4, 128, 128] at entry 10

Tags: python, arrays, deep-learning, pytorch, dataloader

I created a custom ImageFolder with `torch.utils.data.Dataset` class and then converted it to a dataloader, but when I want to see one of the elements of data loader with `img_custom, label_custom = next(iter(train_dataloader_custom))` it gives this error:

"stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 128, 128] at entry 0 and [4, 128, 128] at entry 10"

I resized the images in the custom ImageFolder class to (128,128).

**Important note**: It works sometimes! like I run the cell 6 times and 4 times it works (gives the batch of images and corresponding labels) and 2 times gives error!

how can an image have 4 channels! (in the error it says entry 18 is [4,128,128])

Comment: Images can have an optional alpha channel.

Comment: oooopppps! I didn't know this:( , it seems some of the data have 4 channels (the alpha that you've mentioned) takes, you saved me THANK YOU!